# Displaying a few lines on screen from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have columns ProductId, ProductName, ProductDescription in my database table.

I am saving lots of information in the `ProductDescription` column, but I want to show only few information of `ProductDescription` in the output for each product.

Comment: `TOP(4)`? Be aware you need to order your data (`ORDER BY`), 'first' has no meaning if you don't know the order.

Comment: You should post your sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charindex()` to locate the line end sequence and then `substring()` to get the first part up to the fourth line end sequence. If the text doesn't always end with a line end sequence you have to append it for consistency. If there can be less than four lines, you have to get the maximum possible index of the line end sequence.

Assuming your line end sequence is CRLF (DOS/Windows) this could look like:

```
substring(productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
          1,
          (SELECT max(ci)
                 FROM (SELECT charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                        productdescription + char(13) + char(10)) ci
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                        productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
                                        charindex(char(13) + char(10), productdescription + char(13) + char(10)) + 2) ci
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                        productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
                                        charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                                  productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
                                                  charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                                            productdescription + char(13) + char(10)) + 2) + 2) ci
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                        productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
                                        charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                                  productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
                                                  charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                                            productdescription + char(13) + char(10),
                                                            charindex(char(13) + char(10),
                                                                      productdescription + char(13) + char(10)) + 2) + 2) + 2) ci) x))
```